# Calendar iframe being scrolled to when page laoded

Tags: html, iframe

When my html page loads, the screen is automatically moved to a Calendar iframe I have installed

I've already tried `scrolling="no"` and it didn't work

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some js to your page

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{document.body.scrollIntoView()});
```